# ElasticSearch: Provide inline script using Java API

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to build an aggregation using Java API:

```
GET /sales/t/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_month": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "def opDate = new DateTime(doc['date'].date); opDate.getMonthOfYear()",
        "order": {
          "_term": "asc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Up to now, I've been able to create an `terms aggregation`, however, I'm not able to provide the script:

```
AggregationBuilders.terms(this.getName()).field(this.getName()).script(??????????)
```

Which's the way to provide an inline script using Java API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply like this (no need for `field()` call by the way):

```
AggregationBuilders.terms(this.getName())
    .script(new Script("def opDate = new DateTime(doc['date'].date); opDate.getMonthOfYear()"))
```

Note, though, that your script can be much simpler, like this:

```
doc['date'].date.getMonthOfYear()
```

The reason is because `doc['date'].date` is already a `DateTime` instance

Comment: Solved! Thanks. Nevertheless, this aggregation returns me an `'LongTerms' bucketing aggregation result` with each month as a double. Is there any way to set the `terms` aggregation bucket are longs instead of doubles?

Comment: Sorry, it returns me an `DoubleTerms`